# matlab: creating additional variables in a for loop

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop, matrix

I got the following problem: In my code I want a matrix-...-matrix-vector in a for loop. In every loop I want to get an additional matrix to multiply with, e.g. i=1: P1*z and i=2: P1*P2*z etc. This is my code so far. Obviously it is just computing: i=1: P1*z, i=2: P2*z etc...

```
for ii = 1:10
    % Projection on last_z
    projected_last_z = projection(:,:,ii) * last_z;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually considered bad practice to create new variables in a loop as you want. Better to collect all the results in a [cell array](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) or so:

```
n = 10;
results = cell(1, n);  % preallocate some space
for i = 1:n
    results{i} = some_calculation(i);
end;
```

You can then retrieve the result of the k-th iteration using `results{k}`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to drop the loop completely?

Comment: Yes but my problem is a bit different. I have to calculate again with my result. the 3D Matrix projection is computed at the end of my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You must do compute the value always in the same variable if you want to keep the results

```
n = 10;
projected_last_z = 1;
for ii = 1:n
    projected_last_z = projected_last_z * projection(:,:,ii);
end
projected_last_z = projected_last_z * last_z;
```

The loop is

> loop 1 : projected_last_z = P1
>
> loop 2 : projected_last_z = P1 * P2
>
> ...
>
> loop 10 : projected_last_z = P1 * P2 * ... * P10

Then you multiply the final result by `last_z`